# HBase: Zookeeper tells remote client to connect to localhost

Tags: java, networking, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Super new to HBase/Hadoop here.  I got a two-node HBase test cluster up and running, and I'm now trying to connect to that cluster from a remote Java client.  Here's where I'm stuck: the client successfully connects to the single-server Zookeeper quorum (running on the same server as the HBase master), but the address passed back to the client by Zookeeper is localhost, and (obviously) the client fails to connect to anything because HBase isn't running locally.  Considering that I can't edit the client-side hosts file for administrative reasons (and in any case I'm not inclined to since that seems like an awful hack), is there a way to get Zookeeper to return a proper IP for the HBase master server?

Java code:

```
public static final String MASTER_IP = "10.3.248.105";
public static final String ZOOKEEPER_PORT = "2181";

Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", MASTER_IP);
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", ZOOKEEPER_PORT);

System.out.println("Running connecting test...");

try {
    HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
    System.out.println("HBase found!");
    HTable table = new HTable(config, "testTable");
    System.out.println("Table testTable obtained!");
} catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
    System.out.println("HBase connection failed!");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ZooKeeperConnectionException e) {
    System.out.println("Zookeeper connection failed!");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Error dump:

```
13/06/27 11:20:25 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=10.3.248.105:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/27 11:20:25 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 5896@HQNJVCVM0004
13/06/27 11:20:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 10.3.248.105/10.3.248.105:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
13/06/27 11:20:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 10.3.248.105/10.3.248.105:2181, initiating session
13/06/27 11:20:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 10.3.248.105/10.3.248.105:2181, sessionid = 0x13f8638485c0003, negotiated timeout = 180000
13/06/27 11:20:30 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: localhost.localdomain
HBase connection failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.<init>(HBaseClient.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.createConnection(HBaseClient.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1111)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:712)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1781)
at hbaseimagestore.HBaseImageStore.main(HBaseImageStore.java:44)
13/06/27 11:20:30 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f8638485c0003
13/06/27 11:20:30 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f8638485c0003 closed
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 1 times
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:1781)
at hbaseimagestore.HBaseImageStore.main(HBaseImageStore.java:44)
13/06/27 11:20:30 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

Edit: also, the /etc/hosts file on the master/zookeeper server:

```
10.3.248.105   master
10.3.248.106   slave
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to do this, but it should do the trick. Change the master's hosts file to :

```
10.3.248.105   master     localhost
10.3.248.106   slave
#127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Restart hbase after this change.

Comment: This succeeds in getting the client to query `master` instead of `localhost`, but since `master` isn't defined clientside it also fails to connect.  Is there a way to just get a local IP address back instead of a hostname, or am I going to have to set up a local DNS or something to handle hostname resolution?

Comment: Do the same change in ZK's hosts file as well and see if it helps.

Comment: Zookeeper and master run on the same server, shouldn't they use the same hostfile?

Comment: Yes, they should. Add this line in your code and give it a retry : "config.set("hbase.master", "10.3.248.105:60000");"..This is not at all a tidy solution, but I just want to see if it makes any difference. Change the port as per your configuration.

Comment: Nope, still tries and fails to query master.  `config.set("hbase.master", foo)` is depracated, I think?

Comment: Yes. It is. It seems you need to do what you don't want to do.